# Average Gross Rent

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, us-census

I need an aggregate value for rent using a collection of Census Tracts from the American Community Survey 5-year estimate.

The universe for Aggregate Gross Rent (B25065) is listed as "Renter-occupied housing units paying cash rent", yet there's not table that contains a total for that universe. Would it be safe to use the Renter Occupied column from Tenure (B25003) to calculate an average gross rent even though the universe is "Occupied housing units"?